# Use of unresolved identifier "Model" in core data swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, entity

I am saving the data in an entity named `Forms` but when I am calling the `Forms` it gives me error
Everything was fine, but suddenly error occurred and it now irritates me a lot. I don't know why even there is no any syntax error.

> use of unresolved identifier "Forms"

**Here is my code**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
class ViewViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    // var getAddController : AddViewController = AddViewController()
    var fName : String?
    var fDesc : String?
    var formName : String?
    var results : [NSManagedObject] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var menu: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewTableView: UITableView!

    var manageObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
    var eventArray = [Forms]()  // Where **Forms** is an model name

    let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Forms")
    //var eventRequest: NSFetchRequest<Forms> = Forms.fetchRequest()

    func loadSaveData()  {
        let eventRequest: NSFetchRequest<Forms> = Forms.fetchRequest()
        do{
            eventArray = try manageObjectContext.fetch(eventRequest)
            self.viewTableView.reloadData()
        }catch
        {
            print("Could not load save data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    ...
    table view methods here
    ...

    func moveToEdit() {
        let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle : nil)
        let desController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EditViewController") as! EditViewController
        let newFrontViewController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController:desController)
        revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(newFrontViewController, animated: true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        menu.target = revealViewController()
        menu.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

        let context = appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext
        results = try! context.fetch(request) as! [NSManagedObject]

        viewTableView.delegate = self
        viewTableView.dataSource = self
        viewTableView.reloadData()

        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        manageObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        self.loadSaveData()
    }
}
```

**Update**

after changing from `var eventArray = [Forms]()` to 
     `var eventArray : [NSManagedObject] = []`

I am getting an error inside the  `func loadSaveData()`

```
 let eventRequest: NSFetchRequest<Forms> = Forms.fetchRequest()
```

> use of undeclared type "Forms"

Comment: change   var eventArray = [Forms]()   to  var eventArray : [NSManagedObject] = []

Comment: @Shezad updated question still error

Comment: let eventRequest: NSFetchRequest<Forms> = Forms.fetchRequest() to  let eventRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Forms")

Comment: @Shezad it worked kindly answer so that I can accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Change your eventArray type to NSManagedObject

```
var eventArray : [NSManagedObject] = []
```

2.Updtaed code for your loadSaveData() method.

```
func loadSaveData()  {
    let eventRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Forms")
    do{
        eventArray = try manageObjectContext.fetch(eventRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
        self.viewTableView.reloadData()
    }catch
    {
        print("Could not load save data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```